# I cloned a flutter project from github but I am unable to run it

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have cloned a flutter project from Github (project link: https://github.com/abuanwar072/Covid-19-Flutter-UI.git) and I have not changed anything in the code. I have cloned it in VS Code however when I try to run it on my android emulator, I run into an error.

Log:

```
[38;5;248mLaunching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...[39;49m
 lib\main.dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> File 'C:\Users\RIJAK\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar' specified for property 'androidJar' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have already tried updating my android SDK from the android studio and running flutter doctor (It showed something about licenses so I fixed it by saying yes to all licenses it showed me). It still is producing the above message. I am not sure I did the SDK update part correctly but please help in understanding how to do it correctly.

Comment: Have you tried pub get in the terminal?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but it's still not working.

Comment: Which version of Android SDK do you have installed?

Comment: Maybe run `flutter clean` and then try `flutter run` again.

Answer (score 1):

You should try ***flutter clean***  and after ***flutter run***

If this doesn't work for you then make a new project and copy paste codes and classes instead of taking full project

Answer (score 0):

follow few steps :

1. create your own empty project using cmd( cmd ->locate your path where you want to create your project folder cd "folderName" ->flutter create "YourProjectName")
2. now after creating type command "code ." and you fall directly on vs code
3. open your pubspec.yaml file copy it.
4. now replace that copy code with clone code of pubspec.yaml folder.

now run ---

Hope so its working :)